# Kings Bounty: The Legend - Does advancing/completing the main quest lock off any side quests?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

I have noticed a few side quests being able to be completed in different ways and some that can be failed outright.

I would like to know if continuing the main quest will stop me completing any side quest, as well as if finishing the main story ends the game immediately or will let me return to the game and finish off any remaining side quests.